# Are there modern cognitive techniques for dealing with searching for information online?

Tags: learning, memory

**"Google it"** is a common response to questions nowadays, and it indicates that people are more and more reliant on the internet for all kinds of information. Frequently this information is not memorized, but is retrieved on demand.  My question is about how people retrieve this information efficiently.

For example, knowing a precise keyword, or a model number of a gadget, it is relatively easy to find relevant information or a manual online, but now one has to remember a large number of rarely used keywords or model numbers.

"How to connect second monitor in Windows Vista"
"RJW-500 connect exhaust hose"

but a person new to computers may word the query differently and get a list of irrelevant results

My question is: **are there modern techniques, tips and tricks or mnemonics on how to deal with searching through a lot of information and finding the stuff that you need online?**

Comment: I actually heard a very interesting study about this on the news a month-ish ago, I'll see if I can find it tomorrow!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is too old to migrate to SuperUsers.SE and it isn't really a psychological/neurological question. This is more to do with "Google fu"